# MySQL #1062 while there's no such data in table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mysql-error-1062

`----exception----`

`(1062, "Duplicate entry '1711076-314274483' for key 'uk_thread_mail'")`

this is the exception I printed in my log.

the key is `UNIQUE KEY uk_thread_mail (thread_id, mail_id)`

the log seems telling me that I already got the tuple value (thread_id, mail_id) as (1711076, 314274483), but when I check the table, I can't find any rows matches thread_id=1711076 and mail_id=314274483.

I really wanna know why this would happen.

---

My code looks like:

```
for r, s in rs:
    try:
        store.execute("insert into table_x (thread_id, mail_id) values (%s, %s)", (r, s))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        store.rollback()
    store.commit()
```

---

rows in rs can never be duplicate because mail_id comes from the primary key of another table.

Comment: Are you doing multiple inserts simultaneously?

Comment: I was thinking maybe he `LOAD DATA INFILE` ? and that combination occurs twice in the file

Comment: I inserted the data in a loop, like for r in rs: store.execute("insert into table_x (x, y) values (%s, %s)", (r[0], r[1])); store.commit(); but I'm not sure where the transactions are commited simultaneously.

Comment: You say you can't find rows with those keys.  Are you checking the data source (`rs`), or the destination table (`table_x`)?  If you're looking in `table_x` then the rollback might be preventing you from seeing the rows with that data.

Comment: I check in table_x used `select * from table_x where thread_id= and mail_id=` but empty set is returned. From the exception we can see that duplicate rows accurred in the table which means if I check in the table I can find one row matching, the 2nd row is duplicate. But I got none in table and 2nd row is still duplicate, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Can you verify that the following are true?

1. The `commit` is indeed inside the `for` loop in your original code.  (Double-check the indentation.)
2. There is only one record in `rs` with `r == 1711076` and `s == 314274483`.  (Actually verify this against the data, and don't just assume duplicates can't happen.)

It seems that both of these would need to be false for the duplicate key error to occur and the key not to be present in `table_x`, unless something very unusual is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds unlikely (unless you're performing duplicate inserts as mentioned in the comments). You can try to drop the key or rebuild the index.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.

Ultimately it was due to an bigint (in the source) being cast to an int (in the destination). And causing 'duplicate entries' to be inserted.

If you have a similar casting issues, that might be your problem.